# Excel Group by and Outline in Jasper Reports

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports, grouping

I am using Jasper Reports to export to Excel and I want to know if it's possible to export a spreadsheet with grouping.

I mean, create a report in jasper with data already grouped so that when I open it on excel I can use the +/- buttons to expand/collapse them.

[image: grouping open]

[image: grouping closed]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can do it with help of `net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.row.outline.level.{n}` property.

The information about *export to Excel features* is [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xlsfeatures/index.html).

You can examine the sample in JasperReports package, in `*$jasperreports_folder$\demo\samples\xlsfeatures*` folder.

The sample:

```xml
<group name="citygroup">
    <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{city}]]></groupExpression>
    <groupHeader>
        <band height="20">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["City: " + $F{city}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupHeader>
    <groupFooter>
        <band height="21">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="0" y="1" width="100" height="20">
                    <!-- Outline row group ends here-->
                    <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.row.outline.level.1" value="End"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Total: " + $V{citygroup_COUNT}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </groupFooter>
</group>
<detail>
    <band height="20" splitType="Stretch">
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20">
                <!-- Outline row group starts here-->
                <property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.row.outline.level.1" value="Body"/>
            </reportElement>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{id}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="100" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{name}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
        <textField>
            <reportElement x="200" y="0" width="100" height="20"/>
            <textElement/>
            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
        </textField>
    </band>
</detail>
```

#### Limitation:

This sample works properly (export to *xls* via preview function) in ***iReport 4.1.3 version***, but not in ***4.1.2*** version. May be this is a new feature of ***4.1.3*** version (see [release notes](http://jasperforge.org/wiki/ireport-413-release-notes)).